# How to update endpoint of Autodesk Viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I'm using Autodesk Viewer v7.61 on javascript.

```js
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.61/viewer3D.min.js"></script>
```

According to logs below, I need t update endpoint.
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7/#section-19

How can I set a new endpoint?
Is it ok to just upgrade the version to 7.68?

```js
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.68/viewer3D.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct, using the latest version (or 7.69+) should handle that.

Comment: Thank you!. I appreciate your quick response :)